# Best software to view OLAP Cube

Tags: server, olap, analysis, cube

I connected to an analysis server using (32-bit) Ms Excel, but it crashed since the amount of data was big.
Then I used SQL Server Management Studio, even that did not worked for me since it seems like SSMS is an administrator tool and you need to have administrator rights for the DB you like to view (Which I do not and cannot have).
Please suggest me a software that can allow me to work with the large amount of data (without crashing) coming from an OLAP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio is the right s/w. We need to use the query editor to access the db where we got no admin rights and then use MDX query to pull data.